# std::bad_cast vs NULL, what's the difference?

Tags: c++, exception, casting

Why we need `std::bad_cast` when It returns `Null` when it fails?

I learnt that when `dynamic_cast` fails it returns `Null` So I could check if `Null` was returned it means an error happened.

But why `std::bad_cast` exception was added to C++?

Comment: You might want to read the "blurb" of e.g. [this `std::bad_cast` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast). As well as [this `dynamic_cast` reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast).

Comment: It returns `nullptr` if you try to cast a pointer. It throws an exception if you try to cast a reference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you can't have a null reference.  A `dynamic_cast<T*>` can return `nullptr` as a failure but `dynamic_cast<T&>` can't, since you're returning a reference to the object.  For that case you need an exception to know that the cast failed.

Comment: so why they don't make dynamic_cast<T&> return Null and not a null reference?

Comment: @Daniel Because the return type of `dynamic_cast<T&>` is `T&`.  There is no `null` for that.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::bad_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/bad_cast) is thrown when casting a *reference*

With a pointer cast, as you mentioned you could use `dynamic_cast`

```
Base* b = dynamic_cast<Base*>(a);  // could return nullptr
```

With a reference, you cannot assign `nullptr`

```
try
{
    Base& b = dynamic_cast<Base&>(a);
} 
catch(const std::bad_cast& e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

so `std::bad_cast` provides a mechanism to know that the cast failed.